# Django log out problems

Tags: python, django, authentication, backend, logout

I am developing a tweet application and while I can log in during the authentication process, my logout function does not work. I leave my source codes to explanation. I'm waiting for your help

The error I get is as follows:
(http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout/?next=/) and i get This site cannot be reached error!
More precisely, I cannot access the page I want. When I click on logout, I have to log out of the account.
I should also mention that I am using Python 3.12.0 and Django.

my urls.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include 

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path("",include('tweetapp.urls')),
        path("",include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),]
```

my views.py

````
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from . import models
from django.urls import reverse
from tweetapp.forms import AddTweetForm, AddTweetModelForm

def listtweet(request):
    all_tweets = models.Tweet.objects.all()
    tweet_dict = {"tweets":all_tweets}
    return render(request,'tweetapp/listtweet.html',context=tweet_dict)

def addtweet(request):
    if request.POST:
        nickname = request.POST["nickname"]
        message = request.POST["message"]
        models.Tweet.objects.create(nickname=nickname, message=message)
        return redirect(reverse('tweetapp:listtweet'))
    else:
        return render(request,'tweetapp/addtweet.html')
    
def addtweetbyform(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddTweetForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            nickname = form.cleaned_data["nickname_input"]
            message = form.cleaned_data["message_input"]
            models.Tweet.objects.create(nickname=nickname, message=message
                                        )
            return redirect(reverse('tweetapp:listtweet'))
        else:
            print("error in form")
            return render(request,'tweetapp/addtweetbyform.html', context={"form":form})
    else:
        form = AddTweetForm()
        return render(request,'tweetapp/addtweetbyform.html', context={"form":form})

def addtweetbymodelform(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddTweetModelForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            return redirect(reverse('tweetapp:listtweet'))
        else:
            print("error in form")
            return render(request,'tweetapp/addtweetbymodelform.html', context={"form":form})
    else:
        form = AddTweetModelForm()
        return render(request,'tweetapp/addtweetbymodelform.html', context={"form":form})
    ```


and i share my base.html
````

```
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}?next=/">Logout</a> 
          </li>
```

````
    THX GUYS I SOLVED PROBLEM WITH THIS CODES:
    ```
       <form method="post" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <button class="nav-link" 
       type="submit">Logout</button>
       </form>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

In your `urls.py` you have two routes for "". That is `path("",include('tweetapp.urls'))` and `path("",include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))`

You need to change the one for the account management to something like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]
```

Refer to [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views)

Comment: Now the error I get has changed to the following: I cannot go to this address. http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/logout/?next=/                                                                                   But i can go this addres                                                                                  http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/

Comment: Please include a stack trace with the specific error, you can update your question up there

Comment: Method Not Allowed (GET): /logout/
Method Not Allowed: /logout/
[15/Jan/2024 19:18:08] "GET /logout/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your root for logout. It works for me.

For this, add this to your **urls.py** file :

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("",include('tweetapp.urls')),
    path("",include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path("logout/", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page="/"), name="logout"),]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me. Did you use the next parameter in base.html?

Comment: Yes, try this : path("logout/", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page="/"), name="logout"). ?next is not necessary in your html file.

Comment: I left my html like this: <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>       
and pasted what you said but didnt work http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout/ :((

Comment: Have you all needed middlewares ? Check if you have "django.contrib.auth" and "django.contrib.sessions".